# add/sum different numbers that have a delimiter (space - comma) within the same cell excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i wanto to sum diferente number delimited by space o comma that are in the same cell eg. A1 en excel and i want a result in another cell eg.A2

```
A1      A2
1 2 3 = 6
```

how could o do that?

Comment: Be sure to show enough examples to exhaust all possible combinations. Is it strictly spaces or commas? Or could have you a combination like `1 2, 3`? What have you tried?

Comment: Will your numbers always be less single digit? Guessing not but your sample size is not enough for us t oknow

Comment: hi answering question, my numbers will always be separated by commas, 

eg 1,2,3 it could have a space en between them 1, 2, 3...

and the will have more than one digit

regards

Answer (score 2):

For **comma separated values** in cell **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=SUM((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",255)),1+(ROW(A$1:A$999)-1)*255,255)) & "0")/10)
```

[image]

Comment: I've seen this around and cannot understand how it works for the life of me

Comment: I guess you could just replace spaces with commas to make sure this works for all strings like in OPs example

Answer (score 2):

If one has FILTERXML:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "))," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"))
```

[image]